# Creating an msi containing windows service and other dll files

Tags: windows, dll, service, installation, windows-installer

I have a windows service that installs and runs fine. I want to create an installer/msi bundle that contains the windows service + other .dll files. And when I run the msi, I want it to run the service and the dlls'.

Currently I am at a point where I have a SetUp project which can install and uninstall the windows service that I created. And the dlls that are being used for a specific task also work fine individually. I want a package that would initiate these 2 tasks.

Do I need to use any third-party package creation wizards? Please guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean by "specific task" regarding your DLLs, since DLLs are not executed directly... does your service depend on those DLLs?

I don't want to do commercial but I used http://www.advancedinstaller.com/ with the enterprise license (1k$) for very very easy complicated MSI functionality.

What are you doing with those DLLs? Just install them?

//

Well you can easily deploy your service and related DLLs, and registry settings, .... with that tool i mentioned, but its not for free. But this should be possible without it, I just don't know any tool that gives you an easy interface to creating such MSIs. I don't have any experience with the Visual Studio integraded MSI generation / install projects.

You could "try" the trial ;) The basic/free version does not support this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There are 2 things about dlls - Firstly, my service does depend on few dlls. Secondly, there are other dll files that I need to register and unregister them when I install/uninstall. So my question, how do I initiate these actions while creating an msi? Is it possible to mention this in AdvancedInstaller? Looks like AdvancedInstaller has a trial version, let me explore that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the trial version. And it is just packaging only component, i.e. only windows service. It is not allowing me to add multiple components and does not allow to add the initiation steps there. Is that contained only in the proprietary version?